# Difficult problem in the analysis of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers and let: 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=0$$ Prove that every $a \in (\lim\text{inf}\,a_n, \lim\text{sup}\,a_n)$ is a limit point of $a_n$.

Comment: See the first answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195646/if-a-sequence-satisfies-lim-limits-n-to-inftya-n1-a-n-0-then-the-set).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at $b_n:=a_{n+1}-a_n$ as the terms of a series. You can apply the idea in the proof of the [Riemann series theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem). What are the partial sums of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n$?